Terraform using regex in a for loop
I am trying to populate my targets var with only .domain1.com and .domain2.com from a list in a file that includes the following:
[ *.domain1.com, .domain2.com, domain3.com, domain4.net ]


targets = distinct([
  for line in split("\n", file("./prod-files/managed-domain-list-simplified.txt")) : regex("^\\..*", trim(line, " \r *"))  
  ]  
)

I strip out * because AWS Network Firewall can't deal with domain lists that start with *.
Then I want to grab only entries that start with a period and ignore the rest.
When I apply in TF I get this error twice.

Call to function "regex" failed: pattern did not match any part of the given string.


The regexp matches a string beginning with a literal . character. So it doesn't match domain3.com and domain4.com.

I don't know Terraform, but I guess this means you can't use regex() as a conditional to test if the string matches the pattern. There's probably some other function that acts as a boolean test.

What is the expected outcome?

I think you can use here "if" condition.
I created a variable list:
variable list {
    default = [ "*.domain1.com", ".domain2.com", "domain3.com", "domain4.net", ]
}

and with this condition you can get element which starts from * (you can update the regexp of course):
> [for string in var.list : regex("\\**", string)]
[
  "*",
  "",
  "",
  "",
  "",
]

and with "if" you can check that output contain the value or not, and add it to the list if no value (means we don't find the *):
> [for string in var.list : string if regex("\\*?", string) == "" ]
[
  ".domain2.com",
  "domain3.com",
  "domain4.net",
]

